# How to do screen sharing with simple-peer webRTC SDK

Tags: javascript, webrtc, communication, signaling, simple-peer

I'm trying to implement webrtc & simple peer to my chat. Everything works but I would like to add screen sharing option. For that I tried that:

```js
$("#callScreenShare").click(async function(){
   if(captureStream != null){                
     p.removeStream(captureStream)
     p.addStream(videoStream)
     captureStreamTrack.stop()
     captureStreamTrack =captureStream= null
     $("#callVideo")[0].srcObject = videoStream
     $(this).text("screen_share")
   }else{
     captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true, audio:true})
     captureStreamTrack = captureStream.getTracks()[0]
     $("#callVideo")[0].srcObject = captureStream
     p.removeStream(videoStream)
     console.log(p)
     p.addStream(captureStream)
     $(this).text("stop_screen_share")
   }
})
```

But I stop the camera and after that doesn't do anything and my video stream on my peer's computer is blocked. No errors, nothing only that.

I've put a console.log when the *event stream* is fired. The first time it fires but when I call *the addStream* method, it doesn't

If someone could help me it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is replacing the track. So instead of removing and adding the stream:

```
p.streams[0].getVideoTracks()[0].stop()
p.streams[0].replaceTrack(p.streams[0].getVideoTracks()[0], captureStreamTrack, p.streams[0])
```

This will replace the video track from the stream with the one of the display.

[simple-peer docs](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer#peerreplacetrackoldtrack-newtrack-stream)

Comment: Mate, ```p.streams``` is an empty array

Comment: Or am doing something wrong??

stream is empty while session is on going

Answer (score 0):

The below function will do the trick. Simply call the `replaceTrack` function, passing it the new track and the remote peer instance.

```js
function replaceTrack(stream, recipientPeer ) {
  recipientPeer.replaceTrack(
    recipientPeer.streams[0].getVideoTracks()[0],
    stream,
    recipientPeer.streams[0]
  )
}
```